# How to inject a string in a JAVA servlet´s method?

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection

I am new using dependency injection. Can anyone tell me how to configure a servlet to inject a string URI pointing to a file? The method signature is the following:

```
@Inject

public void setCar(String value) 
 {
        CarUri =value;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try injecting `@Named` fields

```java
// inside module
@Provides
@Named("CarURI")
public String carURI() {
  return "URI";
}
```

```java
@Inject
public void setCar(@Named("CarURI") String value) {
    CarUri = value;
}
```

example:

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guice/guice_field_injection.htm
2. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guice/guice_method_injection.htm

Comment: Thanks! Just what  needed! Cheers!